# Should I use approval tests as part of CI test run?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, approval-tests

What is the common approach for working with CI and ApprovalTests? I've encountered an issue because access to the approval file was denied. So I start to wonder whether I should use ApprovalTests in CI test run. What is the recommended location for approval files for CI scenario?

---

I don't want to put `chmod -R a+x` here and there

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you get access issue with `*.approved.*` files in DevOps, what you need to do is checking in the `*.approved.*` files to DevOps. Check the following documentation:

https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net

> [image]